# Impedir a repetição de um elemento numa parte do código

Tags: java, while

Tenho o seguinte exercício que me pede para definir um intervalo e somar todos os valores pares desse intervalo mostrando quais os números somados entre eles, do género:

> Min=10
>   Max=15
>
> 10+12+14=36.

No entanto. o output que obtenho é:

> 10+12+14+=36.

Ou seja.Tenho um "+" a mais. Deixo aqui o código:

```
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    do{  
        do{
            System.out.println("Insira um valor min:");
            min = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Insira um valor max:");
            max = scanner.nextInt();
        }while (min<0 || max >100);
    }while(min>max);
    int i = 0;
    while((min<max))
    {            
        if(min % 2==0)
        {
            i+=min;
            System . out . print(min + "+");
        }min++;
    }
    System . out . print("=" + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você pode combinar os dois `do-while`s em um só usando um `||` para juntar as condições.

Segundo, para não confundir, ao invés de ficar incrementando `min` e somando em uma variável `i`, deixe `min` inalterado e mude o nome de `i` para `soma`. Declare também uma variável `valor` que corresponde ao valor a ser somado.

Terceiro, usar um `for` é bem mais prático que um `while` neste caso.

Quarto, para arrumar esse problema, ao invés de colocar o `+` após o número e tentar não colocar depois do último, é mais fácil colocar antes do número e não tentar colocar antes do primeiro. O motivo disso é que é mais fácil saber-se qual é o primeiro do que o último. Você pode utilizar uma variável booleana para controlar isso.

```
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Insira um valor min:");
        min = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insira um valor max:");
        max = scanner.nextInt();
    } while (min < 0 || max > 100 || min > max);

    boolean jaFoiOPrimeiro = false;
    int soma = 0;
    for (valor = min; valor <= max; valor++) {
        if (valor % 2 == 0) {
            soma += valor;
            if (jaFoiOPrimeiro) {
                System.out.print("+");
            } else {
                jaFoiOPrimeiro = true;
            }
            System.out.print(valor);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("=" + soma);
```

Comment: Eu prefiro `String sinal = "";...soma+=valor;sysout(sinal+valor);sinal="+"` =)

Comment: @mari Pode ser também.